# MVC remote validation after submit button is pressed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Quick question about remote validation. Im using Remote to check if email is already in use. Problem with this is it instantly check if the email is in use, which i dont want. I want the errormessage displayed AFTER you click the submit button, not as soon as you tab from the email textbox. Is this possible?

**Model:**

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Remote("IsUserEmailAvailable", "Account", ErrorMessage = "Email alrdy in use.")]
```

**Action:**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult IsUserEmailAvailable(string Email)
{
    return Json(!db.UserProfiles.Any(User => User.Email == Email), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model test.Models.RegisterModel

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Registrera" />
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using simple aspnet code,

```
var userWithRequestedEmail = db.UserAccounts.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == SysUser.Email);

if (userWithRequestedEmail != null)
//Email alrdy registered
```